# Cómo mostrar por consola los datos insertados en localstore?

Tags: javascript, html

hola soy nuevo en js y tengo un problemita. tengo este codigo y registro y guardo todo mis datos en el local store pero a la hora de ingresar los datos correctos en mi login me sale los valores null. en mi console.log pareciendo que no encuentra ningun dato que traer quiero que a la hora de darle a iniciar seccio me salgan los valores por consola.aqui esta todo mi codigo.

register

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <form onsubmit="signup()">

            <label for="username">Usuario</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

            <br><label for="email">Correo</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

            <br><label for="password">contrasena</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password">

           <br> <button type="submit">registrar</button>

        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

login

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <form onsubmit="loginfunction()">

            <label for="username">Usuario</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

            <br><label for="password">contrasena</label> <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

           <br> <button type="submit">iniciar sesion</button>
           <p id="result">bienvenido inicia sesion</p>

        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mainjs

```
    // FUNCIONES DEL REGISTRO

    function signup(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log('funcionando');

    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    
    var user = {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        pass: pass,
    };

    var json = JSON.stringify(user);
    localStorage.setItem(user, json);
    console.log('usuario registrado');


    }


    // FUNCIONES INICIAR SECCION

    function loginfunction(e){
        event.preventDefault();

        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var result =  document.getElementById('result');

        var user = localStorage.getItem(username);
        var data = JSON.parse(user);
        console.log(data);

        
    }
```

quisiera a la hora de darle a loguear que me aparezca toda la info de ese usuario logueado y solo me sale null como que no encuentra ningun dato

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código estas guardando el key del dato en formato de objeto, cosa que te va a provocar error al querer recuperar el dato. Al guardar el dato debes mandar dos parámetros: el nombre del Key y el valor a guardar.

Te recomendaría el siguiente código:

```
// Código para guardar usuario

var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;

var user = {
    email: email,
    username: username,
    pass: pass,
};

var json = JSON.stringify(user);
localStorage.setItem("user", json);

// Codigo para iniciar sesión

var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
var result =  document.getElementById('result');

var user = localStorage.getItem("user");
var data = JSON.parse(user);
console.log(data);
```

Si deseas guardar mas usuarios, debes enviar al localStorage un array de objetos, haciendo el mismo procedimiento. Ten en cuenta cambiar el Key de "user" a "users" ya que habrá más de uno.

Ya depende de ti como mostrar los datos, puedes hacerlo como data.username o hacerlo por desestructuración. Espero haber ayudado!